# ASP.NET MVC 4 Facebook template Application Does not get past the permission stage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, templates, visual-studio-2012

I've downloaded and installed the VS2012 Fall Update which introduces the new Facebook Application Template for ASP.NET MVC4 applications.

I've created a facebook app and copied the App ID, App Secret and App Namespace in the web.config of the MVC app. I then ran the app in debug mode, copied the resulting URL (`http://localhost:41999`) in the canvas URL of the facebook application, turned sandbox mode on and hit save.

The problem is that when running the MVC application, I cannot get past the Facebook permission authorization request.

Has anyone encountered this problem ? Please help.

Thank you,
Radu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after a bit of fidgeting with various settings I figured it out.
The problem was that I had filled in the secure canvas url in facebook to a non-existing url.
So I left it blank and then allowed IE to display non-secure content when prompted and it worked.